# Migrating of DNS from GoDaddy to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have a GoDaddy URL that I want to migrate to my website hosted on AWS EC2.

I have followed the steps to transfer the DNS by setting up a hosted zone on Route 53, copying the four Nameservers and saving them in GoDaddy as custom Nameservers.

This was three days ago and the change has still not taken place.

Any ideas as to what I have done wrong?

The url is: www.swsportspsychology.co.uk

These are screenshots of the AWS and GoDaddy accounts:

[image: AWS]
[image: GoDaddy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the domain is not registered!

I would recommend that you double check that GoDaddy actually took payment and submitted the registration - perhaps its still in progress however, I doubt this as you have stated its been 3 days.

Alternatively (and I would recommend this) if you plan to use this domain with AWS why not register it within AWS in the Route53 Service. As you can see from the image below the domain is available for registration in the AWS Console.

This will make management a lot easier in my opinion, however if you choose to pursue the GoDaddy registration it does look like you're all correctly configured to host that site's DNS when the registration takes place. Good work!

[image: Domain not Registered]

**Update: Adding a DNS record to your domain**

In this example we are going to configure the A record for your domain and WWW to point to your EC2 Instance.

1. Open EC2 and highlight your instance, make a note of the Public IP and the Pubic DNS values. Keep these handy.
2. Open Route53 and click your hosted zone "swsportspsychology.co.uk"
3. Click the Blue "Add Record" button.
4. Using the panel on the right hand side;
5. Leave the Name value empty
6. Ensure the Record Type is "A - IPV4 Address"
7. Leave Alias set to "No"
8. Leave TTL as the current value
9. In the Value field, type in the Public IP of your EC2 instance only.
10. Click Create
11. This will create a record for swsportspsychology.co.uk that will take you to your EC2 instance. Now to setup WWW.
12. Click Create Record Set again
13. Using the panel on the right hand side;
14. Enter "www" in the name field
15. Ensure the Record Type is set to "CNAME - Canonical Name"
16. Ensure that the Alias value is set to "No"
17. Leave the TTL value as the default value
18. Set the Value field to be the Public DNS value for your EC2 instance that you recorded earlier.
19. Click Create
20. You should now be able to access your website by visiting "www.swsportspsychology.co.uk"

Comment: It has now worked. But now when I go to my domain name it takes me to the website but the url displayed is the EIP and not the address I have transferred. Any ideas?

Comment: When I dig your domain I can see your domain is now registered however I cannot see any DNS records. What we need to so is setup www.swsportspsychology.co.uk to point to your EC2 Instance. I will update the answer above for you with this additional detail.

Comment: I have updated the question with the steps to add the DNS records you need. Please be aware that your architecture does not lend itself to HA or Scalability. I suggest you check out AWS Elastic Load Balancers and Autoscaling Groups to improve your architecture, as well as Route53 Alias records and how they relate to an ELB.